# What are the advantages of an array vs a vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Frequently 'homework' style questions appear on SO dealing with array overflow, indexing, functions that require a size passing with the array, etc, etc.

What are the advantages of an `array` vs the `std::vector`?

In what situations is it better to use an `array`? It seems many problems can be happily solved by changing an `int[MAX]` to `std::vector<int>` and in almost all code that is seen in these problems, performance sensitivity is not an issue (although this might be an advantage to an `array`, so if so, please explain)

Comment: low level APIs often get/set array parameters, making a vector impractical for that case. Also, stack allocation is faster than heap allocation.

Comment: @RedAlert For those APIs you can use vectors equally well by passing `&vec[0]` instead if `arr`

Comment: Bah - only checked for duplicates using the 'suggested questions' that pop up - nothing useful appeared. This is however clearly a duplicate - will close.

Comment: @MohitJain you can, though you need to reserve enough space in the vector beforehand to do this, which defeats the purpose of using `vector` over `array` in the first place

Comment: @RedAlert: Making sure the `vector` is large enough is no different that making sure an `array` is large enough. It certainly doesn't "defeat the purpose" of using a `vector`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace exactly, it's no different. That means there is no reason to use a vector over an array.

Comment: @RedAlert: Well, I guess there's no reason to ever use `vector` in C++ code. Thanks for your well-informed advice.

Comment: @Blastfurnace unless you want the automatic resizing, size() functions, etc. Things you don't get if you reserve N elements and never use `push_back`

Comment: @RedAlert: or if the size isn't known at compile time or is too large for automatic storage and would overflow the call stack. Thank goodness you can still pass `&vec[0]` to low level APIs which doesn't defeat the purpose of using `vector` over `array` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Not much in the way of difference between the two.

For the most part a Vector will do everything an Array does and will compile to be relatively similar.

One thing that you might note is that a Vector will more than likely move its memory location upon resizing its container(which can be caused by some of its usage functions.) This will break all pointers to data in the vector.

So in the case that you do not want the data location to move, an array's data will not move and may be what you want.

It is still possible to avoid Vector resizing by reserving the amount you need so that it does not resize but the safer method is to just fill the vector with pointers to data instead.